# Rotate Symbol Shape, shape border rotate doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikzlibrary

I'm trying to rotate the signal shape without rotating the text, and I've arrived at the real kludge of rotating the node and the text box.  From what I'm reading, the right way to do this is with "shape border rotate", but I can't make that work.

Is there a better way to do this?  Any particular reason why shape border rotate doesn't do it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw node[shape=signal,draw=black, anchor=east]{Signal 1}
to [R=R1] ++(3,0) node[shape=signal,draw=black, anchor=west, ]{Signal 2};
;
\end{circuitikz}


\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw node[shape=signal,draw=black, anchor=east]{Signal 1}
    to [R=R1] ++(3,0) node[shape=signal,draw=black, anchor=east, rotate=180]{\rotatebox{180}{Signal 2}}; %This Works!!
    ;
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw node[shape=signal,draw=black, anchor=east]{Signal 1}
    to [R=R1] ++(3,0) node[shape=signal,draw=black, anchor=east,  rotate=180]{Signal 2}; %This Doesn't!!
    ;
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw node[shape=signal,draw=black, anchor=east]{Signal 1}
    to [R=R1] ++(3,0) node[shape=signal,draw=black, anchor=west, shape border rotate=180]{Signal 2}; %Nor Does This
    ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use option `signal to=west`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   node[signal,draw, anchor=east]{Signal 1} to [R=R1] ++(3,0)
        node[signal,draw, anchor=west]{Signal 2};
    \end{circuitikz}

    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   node[signal,draw, anchor=east]{Signal 1}to [R=R1] ++(3,0)
        node[signal,signal to=west, draw, anchor=west]{Signal 2}; %This works!
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Sort of begs the question as to how one can find out if some shape-specific key that does exactly what you happen to need exists.